# I want to pass Mysql query through a text box value

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

```
$query="SELECT * FROM table1 where name='Vidya'";
```

My text field is

```
<input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $query;?>' id='getsearchquery' name='getsearchquery'>
```

When I try to alert the Input field value I am getting

```
SELECT * FROM table1 where name=
```

Comment: Instead single quotes, use double quotes to assign to value attribute

Comment: how are you posting or alerting the data, share the code

Comment: @ManiMuthuPandi my input field is also stored in a php variable like: $field="<input type='hidden' ">

Comment: @ManiMuthuPandi My problem is with these quotes I don't know how I handle the issue. Please help

Comment: You are facing the issue with quotes. try to escape the quotes as below

"<input type='hidden' value=\"<?php echo $query;?>\" id='getsearchquery' name='getsearchquery'>"

Comment: Putting a SQL query into a field is a very bad idea.  It's not that hard to change the query by a user, or inject it by a script and your database is then open to whatever a user wants to do with it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to Escape the quotes

```
"<input type='hidden' value=\"<?php echo $query;?>\" id='getsearchquery' name='getsearchquery'>"

//You can assign the input field to a variable as below

$field="<input type='hidden' value=\"$query\" id='getsearchquery' name='getsearchquery'>";
```

Comment: Good to go.

But my suggestion is don't store the entire SQL query string to the Html hidden element. It can be easily hackable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$query="SELECT * FROM table1 where name='Vidya'";
?>
<input type='hidden' value="<?php echo $query;?>" id='getsearchquery' name='getsearchquery'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert($('#getsearchquery').val());
</script>
```

The issue is Vidya word is contained in single quotes and your input filed value is also in single quotes.. Change it to double quotes